# How to use onTerminate() method , android?

Tags: android

I am trying to save some variables using `SharedPreferences`. In my `onCreate()` method I initialize my variables using `SharedPreferences` , and I want when the application ends to store this variables. I am putting this code on the `onTerminate()` method but the variables are never stored. I think that the `onTerminate()` method is never called , as i also see a comment on this method saying `// not guaranteed to be called` . So how can i save the state of my variable just before I stop the application? I know how , I just don't know where to place my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, to be safe, you should save things in onPause() because (at least pre-3.0) your process can be killed by the OS after it calls onPause(). This implies that onStop() and onDestroy() may or may not be called.

In any case, there is no guarantee that onDestroy() will ever be called. If the OS decides to kill your process it won't bother calling onDestroy() on any activities.

Comment: Well i try to use onPause(). When i override it and put in the beginning super.onPause() the compiler says cannot resolve method. If i dont override and dont put super.onPause() , compiler says that the method is never used as a warning. I am sorry if this sounds trivia i am very new to android programming. In another project it worked just fine..

Comment: Sounds like your method signature for onPause() is not identical with the onPause() method you are trying to override. That's also why it is never getting called. Your method signature must look like this: `public void onPause()`. Check that please.

Comment: What do u mean by the method signature? On my code i just place this :   
@Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
}

Comment: Your class, is it derived from Activity?

Comment: from Application. Do u know how i can do this from this class? I am very sorry i didnt mention that before

Comment: No. There are no methods in the Application class that are reliably called when the application exits. Just save your variables whenever they are changed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12303/discussion-between-david-wasser-and-user1372498)

Answer (score 5):

> and i want when the application ends to store this variables.

That will not work, because you do not get control when "the application ends".

Either:

- save the data when the data changes, or
- save the data when the user tells you (e.g., via some sort of Save action bar item), or
- save the data when `onPause()` of the activity where you modified the data is called

Comment: Well i try to use onPause(). When i override it and put in the beginning super.onPause() the compiler says cannot resolve method. If i dont override and dont put super.onPause() , compiler says that the method is never used as a warning. I am sorry if this sounds trivia i am very new to android programming. In another project it worked just fine..

Comment: @user1372498: `onPause()` is a method on `Activity`. As I wrote in my answer, "save the data when `onPause()` **of the activity where you modified the data is called**".

Comment: You are right , but i have like 20 different activities that process this data and "communicate" with the application class. All the variables are local so if i save on the activity , the variable in the application class wont be stored. So i guess i must use a global variable where all the activities can see? Thats why i am asking if theres a way to do something just before the application stops.

Comment: @user1372498: "i have like 20 different activities that process this data and "communicate" with the application class" -- all three bullet points in my answer are still valid. "So i guess i must use a global variable where all the activities can see?" -- you could do that instead of the custom `Application`, but you still need to implement one of the strategies outlined in my bullets. "Thats why i am asking if theres a way to do something just before the application stops." -- as I wrote in my answer, you do not get control "just before the application stops".

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use this function.

> This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate())

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in onPause() too, depending on what you need.
In this case it will save everytime your app lost focus.